# what does "Since version 5.0" mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I want to know the exact meaning of since in terms of versions.I am in a bit confusing whether since 5.0 means from version 5.0 or up to version 5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicates an inclusive, open-ended range. So version 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

"Since version 5.0" means in versions 5.0 and later.